# Can't distinguish two mdpi devices

Tags: android, dpi

I want to declare two different  values for a widget, having two test devices:

- The first has a `480x800 mdpi` display
- The second is `320x480 mdpi`

Both are `mdpi`, but I need a way to name another `values-mdpi` folder that will contain smaller values for the second device. I tried several names based on [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), but everytime the smaller device assumes the same values of the bigger one. Advices?

Comment: `480x800 mdpi` I guess you mean `480x800 hdpi`, because a 480*800 device (as well as an 480*854 device or a 540*960 device) is normally **hdpi**, not **mdpi**

Comment: How about the `5.1'' WVGA 480x800 mdpi` device that is listed on the default configurations (on Eclipse)?

Comment: I guess that's a tablet. These devices follow a different drawable and layout naming. Try: `drawable-w480dp-h800dp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to distinguish between different screen sizes, use the smallest width qualifier

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali

```
res/layout-sw600dp //e.g. all tablets that are > 7"
```

> The Smallest-width qualifier allows you to target screens that have a
>   certain minimum width given in dp. For example, the typical 7" tablet
>   has a minimum width of 600 dp, so if you want your UI to have two
>   panes on those screens (but a single list on smaller screens), you can
>   use the same two layouts from the previous section for single and
>   two-pane layouts, but instead of the large size qualifier, use sw600dp
>   to indicate the two-pane layout is for screens on which the
>   smallest-width is 600 dp:

Answer (score 0):

How about a combination of available height & available width, like values-w480dp-h800dp for the 1st one and the normal values-mdpi folder for the latter one?